# What is Charles Burnside's relation to Albert Fish and how much of his deeds is of his own volition?

Tags: character-motivation, the-dark-tower, black-house

In Stephen King's and Peter Straub's novel *Black House* a Wisconsin small town is haunted by a serial killer named the "Fisherman" because he seems to copy the methods of serial killer Albert Fish from the early 20th century, specifically eating body parts, preferrably the buttocks, of the children he abducts and murders. Early on it is made apparent, that the Fisherman, at least in his physical agency in our world, is Charles Burnside, an octogenerian living in the local elder care. However, Burnside is in turn possessed by Mr. Munshun, a demonic entity from another world working for none other than the Crimson King and seeking out telekinetically gifted children to work as Breakers in the Crimson King's endeadour to bring down the Dark Tower.

But while Charles "Chummy" Burnside has himself formerly been a Chicago gangster and convicted child molester named Carl Bierstone, it is **implied that Albert Fish and other serial killers have also been possessed by Mr. Munshun** in the past, which would explain the similarity in their methods. So I thought that the Fisherman's cannibalistic urges actually stem from Mr. Munshun, something he does on the side for his own pleasure with the kids that are not talented enough to become Breakers. However, in the end it is made clear that **it is Charles Burnside's own desire**, when he intends to slice up and eat Tyler Marshall ostensibly unbeknownst to Mr. Munshun.

Now Chummy and Mr. Munshun are certainly both deranged and evil psychopaths and probably resonate with eachother to some degree. But if it was inherently Charles Burnside's desire to eat the children and Mr. Munshun is just trying to do his job for the Crimson King, then **why is Chummy so closely immitating the deeds of Albert Fish** (or what's the point of Mr. Munshun possessing cannibals anyway)? Or has Charles Burnside just been a "normal" child molester and the cannibalism is something he adopted from Mr. Munshun later on? What exactly is the relation between the two and **which parts of Charles Burnside's deeds are driven by Mr. Munshun and which are of his own volition?**

Comment: I think that there is no way for us to know if it is demonic entity that corrupts already corruptible and bad people and to what extent.

Comment: Maybe there's something about human cannibalism that makes such individuals more susceptible to possession by Mr. Munshun.